# What does "media time" mean here?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

"He has offered to hold elections, but the demonstrators want a fairer election law and more media time for the opposition."

What does "media time" mean here?

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("no research / ELL"), as there's no special idiom here: *media time* means *time in the media*. Hi Lex, it's important to look up a term online before you ask this kind of question here, as it will often provide the solution. Our [Help Centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says "Be sure to [mention the research you've done](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/5043) and what you're still hoping to learn!" For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial thought  is that it refers to time that the opposition candidate(s) gets media coverage.  Usually a candidate from a major Party would get the most amount of time and coverage in the media. It is often times skewed towards one side or the other, and in the case of Independents, Libertarians or others, the media coverage is usually slim to none.

Comment: add a citation to your answer to enhance it

Comment: And it needs to be noted that in some countries the government controls, to one degree or another, what the media covers.  Often the "press" is told what they can cover and what they can't, either explicitly or by various "hints" behind the scenes.